# Cambiar color a accordion de Materializecss

Tags: javascript, css3, materialize, color, accordion

Tengo un accordion de Materialize que al hacer click muestra una tabla, lo que quiero hacer es que al dar en el "títutlo" (el div que tiene la clase collapsible-header) se cambie la clase de color de ese mismo div y al vovler a dar click vuelva al color original, pongo una captura de lo que pretendo hacer.

[image: Imagen de accordion de materializecss] 
[image: Imagen de accordion de materializzecss]

[Documentación de accordion de Materializecss](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html)

Comment: Ya lo intenté pero no funcionó

Comment: he agregado una respuesta para ver si te es de ayuda y he borrado mi comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con añadir este estilo debería funcionar:

```
li.active .collapsible-header{ 
    background-color:red; 
    color:white;//este es solo para mi ejemplo
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

**EDIT**

Si quieres mantener las clases que tenias ya asignadas, esto podria funcionarte:

```
li.active .collapsible-header{ 
    background-color:red!important; 
    color:white;//este es solo para mi ejemplo
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

```css
li.active .collapsible-header{ 
   background-color:red!important; 
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
          <li class="active">
            <div class="collapsible-header blue-grey darken-1" tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i></div>
            <div class="collapsible-body" style="display: block;"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header blue-grey darken-1" tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons">place</i></div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header blue-grey darken-1" tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i></div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Ya vi por que no funciona, el hecho de que le ponga las clases "blue-grey darken-1" para que inicialmente estén en color gris hace que al hacer click no se cambie a color rojo.

Comment: https://codepen.io/JCarlos_Cst/pen/JvomzZ

En ese link ya puse de ejemplo ya puse el primer elemento en color gris y no cambia pero los otros que no tienen las clases si cambia el color.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, si vuelves a ejecutar el código ya cambia de color. el truco fue poner `background-color:red!important;` como te comente en la edición de la misma.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias, como no actualice la página no vi el cambio al ejecutar el código.